# Google Script Dynamic Data Validation

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following Script.  This script takes the active sheets named ranges and uses them as a dynamic data valdiation.  however I would like to make it where it will take the named ranges from another independent sheet and use that data rather then witin the same sheet.

Is this possible?

```
function depDrop_(range, sourceRange){
    var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(sourceRange, true).build();
    range.setDataValidation(rule);
}

function onEdit (){
    var aCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
    var aColumn = aCell.getColumn();
    if (aColumn == 4 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()){
        var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
        var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
        depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
    }
    else if (aColumn == 4 && SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()){
        var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(aCell.getRow(), aColumn + 1);
        var sourceRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName(aCell.getValue());
        depDrop_(range, sourceRange);
    }
}
```